# Conditional Probability of joint discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have screenshot the entire question, but I have only about (f). How do you find the probability of P(Z|X=3)? I am confused about that part. I understand how the expected value is calculated. I just don't understand how they derive the probability for each of those values. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $X=3$, $Z$ could be $9$ (when $y=3$), $6$ (when $y=2$), or $3$ (when $y=1$). It also has the same probabilities as $P(y=3)$, $P(y=2)$, and $P(y=1)$. Hence $\mathbb{E}(Z|X=3) = 9*5/20+6*10/20+3*5/20 = 6$.

In case of you do not know, $P(y=3)$ is the sum of probabilities in the first row, etc.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!